# How to upload python script in django form and use it for some processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms, django-forms

I want to upload python file through django form and read the function available inside and use it for processing.

Till now what i had done is:
Taken file from the user and saved in the media folder.
taken function name (so that i can use it if required for calling funtion)

Index.py

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/result">Enter function name
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="functionname"><br>
Upload your .py file here
<input type="file" name="functionfile">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">  

</form>
```

views.py

```
def result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        functionname=request.POST['functionname']
        functionfile=request.FILES['functionfile']
        fs= FileSystemStorage()
        modulename=fs.save(functionfile.name,functionfile)
        url=fs.url(modulename)
        print(url)

    return render(request,'result.html')
```

I don't have any clue how to use that the function of the uploaded file in the backend

Desired result would be something like.

1. for eg. example.py file contains a function

   def add(data):
   p=10+data
   return p
2. i upload a example.py file
3. suppose in background i have d = 100
4. django calls result=add(d)
5. print the result

Any reference or resource will also be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An simple approach would be use the normal file upload in django get the data in an action, launch a subprocess using docker which has python3 in it on the server side where you are running django application.

Why docker ?
It is safer to run even malicious code inside the docker container rather than on the server machine itself.

Other Ideas :
You can run the code and get result through online API's.

REF : https://github.com/saikat007/Online-Compiler-using-Django-python/blob/master/src/ide/views.py

Comment: Could you please elaborate what i actually need to do...the way i had read the file and stored it in media folder is it fine? where the docker comes into play, do i have to dockerize full Django application or only some part of it.. I don't know much about docker... could you please explain in detail what i actually needs to do ? Thanks 

Comment: This blog will give you an reference:  https://blog.remoteinterview.io/how-we-used-docker-to-compile-and-run-untrusted-code-2fafbffe2ad5