# Why subprocess module giving weird output when calling other script in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, subprocess

I have 2 files

1. a.py
2. b.py

i am using subprocess module from a.py to run script of b.py and it's not giving any error instead giving weird output.

**code in a.py**

```
import subprocess
h=12
res=subprocess.check_output(["python","b.py",'h'])
print(res)
```

**Code in b.py**

```
def test(h):
    h=h*12
    print(h)
    return h
```

Output that i am getting is :

```
b''
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `b.py` script needs to read from `sys.argv` in some way to do something with the parameter(s) you pass in `subprocess.check_output([...])`. Also, the function `test` in your `b.py` script isn't being invoked anywhere, so you'll have to invoke it somewhere.

Additionally, in the `subprocess.check_output` call, the third item in your arguments list is `"h"`, which is a string literal containing a single character. If you want to pass your variable `h`, you should be doing `["python", "b.py", str(h)]`. Note that this will still be interpreted as the string `"12"` when your `b.py` script reads it from `sys.argv`, so if you want to do integer math with it like `h = h * 12`, you will have to cast it to an integer again.

Comment: is their any other way to run b.py file without modifying b.py file ?

Comment: @Razeun No, you'll have to modify `b.py`. Is something preventing you from doing so?

Comment: yes , actually why 
i want to use subprocess is defined here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665874/how-to-upload-python-script-in-django-form-and-use-it-for-some-processing/62670439#62670439  from this you can easily conclude that i cannot change this file it's user uploaded file...if you can suggest something for the question that i had given link for then it would be more than awesome .